# Null Reference Exception When Raising Event in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

What would be the equivalent C# code against following VB.Net code:

```
Public Event EndOfVideo()

Private Sub RaiseEndOfVideo()
        RaiseEvent EndOfVideo()
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Here is the equivalent C# code that telerik converter generated for me.

```
public event EndOfVideoEventHandler EndOfVideo;
public delegate void EndOfVideoEventHandler();

private void RaiseEndOfVideo()
{
    if (EndOfVideo != null) {
        EndOfVideo();
    }
}
```

Calling RaiseEndOfVideo doesn't trigger/invoke EndOfVideo event, and Null Reference Exception is raised.

Comment: Did you try writing any c# code for this or directly asking question here? Did you look in Google for online code converter which can convert vb.net code to c# and vice versa? What problem did you face while using one of them?

Comment: Yes, I did that using telerik convertor but the equivalent c# code line to raise event throws null reference exception.

Comment: If event is not attached to any handler it will throw the error so its nothing to do with syntax but the logic. You might want to read about events and event handlers in c# for this.

Comment: I think I've to set bounty for this simple question then maybe someone write a simpler answer.

Comment: If you can learn the concept by putting bounty, no harm in doing that.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I thought I might get a quick answer on SO for a simple VB code conversion, for now. I will read events concepts in detail later.

Comment: Couple of useful answer are posted below. That should help you to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider you have class `VideoPlayer` which has event `EndOfVideo` and you want to raise this event and when someone calls method `EndVideo` on object of `VideoPlayer`.

Now, like any other member of a class event also initialized to `null` and gets the value when some handler is attached to it.

Attaching an handler to an event happens using `+=` operator.

```
public class VideoPlayer
{
    public event EndOfVideoEventHandler EndOfVideo;
    // Following delegate indicates that the a method accepting no parameter
    // and returning void can be attached as an handler to this event.
    public delegate void EndOfVideoEventHandler();

    public void EndVideo()
    {
        RaiseEndOfVideo();
    }

    private void RaiseEndOfVideo()
    {
        if (EndOfVideo != null)
        {
            // Following line of code executes the event handler which is 
            // attached to the event.
            EndOfVideo();
        }
    }
}

public class WebPage
{
    public void VideoStopped()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Video Stopped");
    }
}
```

Now in `Main` method of  `program.cs`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    VideoPlayer player = new VideoPlayer();
    WebPage page = new WebPage();

    player.EndOfVideo += page.VideoStopped;

    // Following method call on player object will call internally 
    // RaiseEndOfVideo  which will Raise event and event will execute 
    // VideoStopped method of page object which is attached in previous line 
    // and display "Video Stopped" message in Console.
    player.EndVideo();

    Console.WriteLine("Completed!!! Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I hope this would help you start understanding how events and delegates work in C#. For further reading you can go thru https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks @chetan for answering in detail. I believe, the only thing I missed was I didn't subscribe to that event. Once I attached the handler to that event, null reference exception gone.

Comment: Good that I could help you. C# raises NullReferenceException if we try to raise event and there is no handler attached to it. That's why checking null of it mandatory to avoid runtime blasts.

Comment: I believe, VB also raises NRE if there is no handler attached but I didn't realize that before.

Answer (score 1):

This is the generally accepted way to write an event with no parameters:

```
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler EndOfVideo;

    protected virtual void OnEndOfVideo()
    {
        var handler = EndOfVideo;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Your code is what was needed in the old days: creating a delegate and yada yada.

To state the obvious, though, you need to **subscribe** to an event with something like:

```
public class Bar
{
    public void DoAllTheThings()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.EndOfVideo += foo_EndOfVideo;
    }

    void foo_EndOfVideo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EndOfVideo");
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness, the `EventHandler` delegate has a generic counterpart, `EventHandler<T>`, which you would use when you want an event that does have parameters, where `T` should be a class inheriting from `System.EventArgs` which holds the information you want your event to expose.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you will need to create a custom eventHandler to specify the method signatures of the handlers for your event